# Edittext sin texto en app, pero si aparece en preview?

Tags: android, xml, edittext

Tengo un problema que me parte la cabeza, recientemente cambie el manifest y le puse no actionbar desde ahi se movio todo y y ya no aparecen letras en los edit text paso fotos de lo que pasa y codigo, espero me puedan ayudar porfavor [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Aqui se ve como se deberia ver! y asi pasa con otras activities]

dejo mi codigo xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTransfer"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Transferencias"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/menuco"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/Btn_CO"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Btn_CO"
    android:background="@color/white" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_CD"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cuenta Destino: "
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Btn_CO"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="#D82FFF"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/menucd"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Btn_CD"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Btn_CO"
    android:background="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvimporte"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Btn_CD"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#D82FFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Importe: "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etimporte"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:hint="Ejemplo: $500"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvimporte"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvimporte"
    />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvconcepto"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvimporte"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="#D82FFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Concepto: "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etconcepto"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:hint="Ejemplo: Trabajo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tvconcepto"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvconcepto"
    />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvfecha"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvconcepto"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#D82FFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fecha: "
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etfecha"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvfecha"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Btn_CO"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="dd/mm/aaaa" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Enviar"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enviar!"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvfecha"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="#D82FFF"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="Enviar"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Btn_Agregar_Cuenta"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Btn_Enviar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Btn_CO"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Agregar cuenta!"
    android:textColor="#D82FFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coseleccionada"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cdseleccionada"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="122dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Ya lo arregle, faltaba esta linea en el manifest. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"

Comment: Crea una respuesta a tu pregunta para beneficio de los futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arregle, faltaba esta linea en el manifest. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"